# MongoDB, finding all documents where property id equals to record id

Tags: mongodb

I've got collection like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("546089aaf83a94de268a35c3"),
  "parent" : {
        "$ref" : "someRef",
        "$id" : ObjectId("546089aaf83a94de268a35c3"),
        "$db" : "someDB",
    }
}
```

How can I look for all the record where _id is equal to parent.id?

Tried `find({"parent.$id": "_id"})` but obviously that can't be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent` here holds the **[database reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)**. Thus we need to call the getter method of the reference to get its object ID.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function(){
        return this._id.toString() == this.parent.getId().toString();
    }
}).pretty()
```